# React-Navigation to goBack() to defined screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm struggling with what I would hope is a simple issue. I have multiple StackNavigators with various screens. 
Like this:

> **Main Stack**
>     Main Screen (entry)
>
> **Chat Stack**
>   Chat list
>   Chat Details Screen
>   Add Member to list
>   Invite friend to chat

On the Chat List a user can navigate to Invite friend to chat screen. So Chat List Screen > Invite friend to chat screen. This works great, as it does throughout the app.

Navigation in the same stack works great both forward. I'm using the standard .navigate to move forward.

this.props.navigation.navigate('Invite friend to chat')

Here after successfully inviting friend i am navigating to Chat List screen.

> Here i want to remove active screen from stack while navigating to new screen

Link Referred [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop)

E.g.

> ```
> Going back from a specific screen
> Consider the following navigation stack history:
> navigation.navigate(SCREEN_KEY_A);
> ...
> navigation.navigate(SCREEN_KEY_B);
> ...
> navigation.navigate(SCREEN_KEY_C);
> ...
> navigation.navigate(SCREEN_KEY_D);
> Now you are on screen D and want to go back to screen A (popping D, C, and B). Then you need to supply a key to goBack FROM:
> navigation.goBack(SCREEN_KEY_B) // will go to screen A FROM screen B
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't totally clear to me, but it sounds like you'd like this behavior...

```
A > B > C > D > goBack() => A
```

Would the following also be true?

```
A > B > C > goBack() => A
A > B > goBack() => A
A > goBack() => A
```

If so, then rather than `navigation.navigate()` which pushes a new scene onto the navigation stack, you'll want to use `navigation.reset()`. For more information, see the [React Navigation Docs (Reset)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset)

Comment: i want to navigate from
A to B,
but before navigating to Screen B i want to remove Screen A from Stack Is it possible

Comment: That doesn't help clarify for me.

Comment: Yes, the same solution should help you

Comment: Hi Chris i used the above solution it works perfect for app back button, but on device back button of android i am still able to see previous screens can you help out

Comment: Sure! Can you setup a demo on expo snack I can play with?